# SharePoint page using address with the 365 connected domain

Tags: dns, microsoft365

I have a 365 tenant on domain {somename}.onmicrosoft.com and a connected domain {othername}.com

I was able to create users as {username}@{othername}.com
I wonder how I can have pages show with https://{othername}.com ?
Is there an admin action to take or should I add a CNAME?

Thank you

Comment: This question would probably be better to ask on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have added domain as your tenant domain you can manage DNS via your office 365 admin portal https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?source=applauncher#/Domains
You can simply add an A record to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, you can forward sub domain (like www. for example) at the domain manager. it is not a CNAME.

So now  https://www.{othername}.com will take me to {somename}.onmicrosoft.com but will also show {somename}.onmicrosoft.com in the address bar but that's OK.

Thanks